# .htaccess URL Rewrite if a parameter is not exist

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Below is the code which i use to url rewrite in our `.htaccess` file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule pages/(.*)/? /page/index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```

from the above code if the url is `www.example.com/pages/2` then actually it goes to url `www.example.com/page/index.php?name=2`

but also i want something like this : if a page request is `www.example.com/pages/2/user/rahul` then it should also go to same url `www.example.com/page/index.php?name=2&user=rahul`

so doing the above thing i did something like this :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule pages/(.*)/? /page/index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule pages/(.*)/user/(.*)/? /page/index.php?name=$1&user=$2 [NC,L]
```

but it does't work how i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try :

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/user/([^/]+)/?$ /page/index.php?name=$1&user=$2 [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^pages/([^/]+)/?$ /page/index.php?name=$1 [NC,L]
```